# Query to match content of two fields in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, kibana

I'm using ElasticSearch with Kibana for visualization. I want to build a query to match two different fields when they have the same content. 
For example:

> field1: address = google.com 
> field2: hostname = google.com

Is ist possible to match two fields without knowing their values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using painless script. The query will look as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['address'].value == doc['hostname'].value",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To use in [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html#create-scripted-field) you can create [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html).

Comment: Thank you. Could i work with wildcards too? The values of the fields arent exactly the same, so i want to search for something like this: doc['address'].value == (wildcard) doc['hostname'].value (wildcard). Is this possible?

Comment: You can use regex but I don't recommend it because bad regex can lead to disaster. This is why you have to explicitly enable regex which is by default disabled to be used.